# Javascript set CSS Class for Multiple Elements (one element set, remaining elements unset)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a website which has a few filter buttons which are grouped into several groups. I am trying to find a way to set the class of one of these buttons to "filter-set" while all other buttons in the group are set to "not-set".

Each button is a DIV with a unique ID.

i have some bloated code where each button has its own function and sets the associated buttons to "not-set" but this seems inefficient and im sure there's a better way!

Bloated code example:

```
            function setClassR(){
                document.getElementById('filter_rare').className= 'filter-set';
                document.getElementById('filter_common').className= 'not-set';
                document.getElementById("filter_occasional").className = 'not-set';
                }
            function setClassC(){
                document.getElementById('filter_rare').className= 'not-set';
                document.getElementById('filter_common').className= 'filter-set';
                document.getElementById("filter_occasional").className = 'not-set';
                }
            function setClassO(){
                document.getElementById('filter_rare').className= 'not-set';
                document.getElementById('filter_common').className= 'not-set';
                document.getElementById("filter_occasional").className = 'filter-set';
                }
```

I would like to be able to have a function for each group of filters which when run using an `onClick=function()` sets the clicked button to "filter-set" and all others to "not-set"

I have tried the following code but it doesnt appear to run:

```
function setClassSeas(rareClass, commonClass, occClass) {
                      setClass("filter_rare", rareClass);
                      setClass("filter_common", commonClass);
                      setClass("filter_occ", occClass);

                    }

            function setClass(IDName, displayValue) {
              var items = document.getElementById(IDName);
              for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
                items[i].className = (displayValue? "filter-set" : "not-set");
              }
            }
```

UPDATE///

HTML Code for the Divs acting as buttons:

```
    <div id="filter_rare" title="Rare" 
    class="not-set"   
    onclick="chosenFrequency('frequency=Rare'); setClassR();"></div>

    <div id="filter_common" title="Common" 
    class="not-set" 
    onclick="chosenFrequency('frequency=Common'); setClassC();"></div>

    <div id="filter_occasional" title="Occasional" 
    class="not-set" 
    onclick="chosenFrequency('frequency=Occasional'); setClassO();"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post the html code for the buttons?

Comment: Hey @BattlFrog, code updated as requested. Sorry should have uploaded that from the start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `setClass` function according to this. Hope it will work. `document.getElementById()` function will always return a single element (not a list of elements). Even if you have multiple elements having the same ID this function will always return the first element having the given ID. Do not forget to call your `setClassSeas()` function from html.

```js
function setClassSeas(rareClass, commonClass, occClass) {
    setClass("filter_rare", rareClass);
    setClass("filter_common", commonClass);
    setClass("filter_occ", occClass);
}

function setClass(IDName, displayValue) {
    var item = document.getElementById(IDName);
    item.className = displayValue ? "filter-set" : "not-set";
}
```

```html
<div id="filter_rare" title="Rare" class="not-set"
    onclick="chosenFrequency('frequency=Rare'); setClassSeas(true, false, false);"></div>

<div id="filter_common" title="Common" class="not-set"
    onclick="chosenFrequency('frequency=Common'); setClassSeas(false, true, false);"></div>

<div id="filter_occasional" title="Occasional" class="not-set"
    onclick="chosenFrequency('frequency=Occasional'); setClassSeas(false, false, true);"></div>
```

Comment: Why did you create two separate snippets, each not runnable on its own?

Comment: @connexo I mistakenly did it. Whether I would put all those codes into the same snippet still it would not show any output. Because we are not providing those css classes here.

Answer (score 4):

If every button has a class, say `filter-button`, then you can address all buttons at once.
In modern development you should [*attach* an event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of using inline *onclick* handlers.

With all buttons having a common class you can find them all at once. I'm changing your buttons to look like this, adding the *"filter-button"* class and removing the *onclick* handler:

```
<div id="filter_rare" title="Rare" 
     class="filter-button not-set">Rare</div>
```

(I've put text in the div just to simplify this demonstration)

Now collect all the filter buttons:

```
let filters = document.querySelectorAll('div.filter-button');
```

This gets you a *NodeList* of elements (kind of like an Array but not one) You'll want to attach an *onclick* event handler to each of the buttons. To do this you can use the [NodeList.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) call.

```
filters.forEach(node => node.addEventListener('click', someFunction));
```

In the function that gets called when you click a button, you want to clear any `filter-set` class that's currently set, put back the original `not-set` class, then set the `filter-set` class only on the button that was clicked. This will look something like this:

```
function someFunction(event) {
    // again, use forEach to do the same thing to each filter button
    filters.forEach( function(node) {
        node.classList.remove('filter-set');
        node.classList.add('not-set');
    } );
    // now add the 'filter-set' class on the button that was clicked
    event.target.classList.add('filter-set');
}
```

The good thing about using [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead of just doing `className="something"` is that classList can add/remove classes while leaving other classes alone; doing `className="something"` wipes out all the classes that are present and replaces them with "something".

Putting that all together, and using an anonymous function instead of named function gives this snippet:

```js
let filters = document.querySelectorAll('div.filter-button');
filters.forEach(node => node.addEventListener('click',
            function(event) {
                console.log(event.target);
                filters.forEach(function(node) {
                    node.classList.remove('filter-set');
                    node.classList.add('not-set');
                });
                event.target.classList.add('filter-set');
            }));
```

```css
/* Make these look like buttons; put a green border on them */
.filter-button {
    min-height: 2ex;
    max-width: 12em;
    padding: .25em;
    margin: .7em .3em;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

/* use a Red border on any button that has "filter-set" */
.filter-button.filter-set {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

/* limit the height of the stack-snippet console */
div.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="filter_rare" title="Rare" 
     class="filter-button not-set">Rare</div>

<div id="filter_common" title="Common" 
     class="filter-button not-set">Common</div>

<div id="filter_occasional" title="Occasional" 
     class="filter-button not-set">Occasional</div>
```

Using the class `not-set` is really redundant — you could just have no extra class on buttons by default and it would simplify things a little. Buttons would have the class(es) `filter-button` or `filter-button filter-set`.

Comment: Really, this is so much better of an answer. It should definitely be the selected answer.

Comment: Thanks @connexo - the other answer was already accepted before I started this, and it took me a while to write it up.

Comment: @StephenP i appreciate the time you put into explaining your answer, its really helpful.

i have multiple sets of these buttons which relate to different categories (e.g. "Frequency" - as above, or "Season") and i don't want to select a button from one category and reset buttons from another category if that makes sense. Can your answer be adapted to only affect the buttons from the same category that was clicked?

Comment: @AndyKing - yes, it's a pattern I use in cases like this. Contain each set of related buttons in a common parent. The parent can be a div, section, anything really since you can style it. Give the parent a class, maybe `class="filterset"`. When a button is pressed you climb the DOM to find the containing `filterset` and then modify only the buttons within that parent. `querySelectorAll` can be called given any element, not just on `document.`, so doing `aFilterSet.querySelectorAll('.filter-button')` will get the buttons _only_ within that parent. Also personally I'd use `<button>` not `<div>`

Answer (score -1):

Here is *another* (as in "alternative") way to do it (but with jQuery, oh no!)

```js
$('body').click(function(e) {
  let $clicked = $(e.target);
  console.log("Clicked " + $clicked.attr('id'))

  if ($clicked.hasClass('filter')) {
    let $filters = $clicked.closest('.filter-group').find('.filter');
    let unset = $clicked.hasClass('set');
    $filters.toggleClass('not-set', true);
    $filters.toggleClass('set', false);
    if (!unset) {
      $clicked.toggleClass('not-set', false);
      $clicked.toggleClass('set', true);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
button.filter.not-set {
  background: white;
}

button.filter.set {
  color: white;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-group">
  <button id="filter_rare" class="filter not-set">
filter_rare
</button>
  <button id="filter_common" class="filter not-set">
filter_common
</button>
  <button id="filter_occasional" class="filter not-set">
filter_occasional
</button>
</div>

<div class="filter-group">
  <button id="filter_one" class="filter not-set">
filter_one
</button>
  <button id="filter_two" class="filter not-set">
filter_two
</button>
  <button id="filter_three" class="filter not-set">
filter_three
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: OP is not using jQuery, and the question isn't tagged jQuery either. -1 for suggesting a jQuery solution.

Comment: Oh, ok I was pretty sure I saw a jquery tag before the question was edited, whatever

Comment: There was no jQuery tag before the edit. You can check by yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56761714/revisions

Comment: Like I said, whatever. I have now noted that my solution requires jQuery. It is still a working, alternative, solution that may be useful to others, I'm leaving it.

Comment: @ArleighHix thanks for the suggestion. I always find it interesting to see how different people tackle the same problem. Im not looking for a jQuery solution but thanks anyways :)